# Update SQL Database Columns

Tags: java, android, database, sql-update

I know there has been a lot of these questions, but unfortunately none of these helps me with my problem.

With a button click i want to add some new content to my database,
or the existing columns should be overwritten. Adding the content to my database works fine. But if i want to overwrite the existing content, my code just adds a new row to the database.

This is my Code:

**Main Activity: Add Content With Button To BD**

```
btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    btnAdd .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ListView shopList= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvShopList);


            for(int i = 0; i < dataSource.size();i++){
                tvname = (TextView) shoppingList.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.tvName);
                tvamount= (TextView) shoppingList.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.tvAmount);

                String nameTV = tvname.getText().toString();
                String amaountTV = tvamount.getText().toString();

                ingredient.setName(nameTV);
                ingredient.setAmpunt(amaountTV );
                myDB.getInstance(MainActivity.this).increaseIngredient(ingredient);
            }
        }
    });
```

**This Is My DB Class**

```
public Ingredient increaseIngredient(final Ingredient ingredient){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(COL_NAME, ingredient.getName());
    values.put(COL_AMOUNT, ingredient.getAmount());

    long newID = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
    return getiIngredient(newID);

    //Also tried this code, but with this, nothing will be shown:
    // db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(ingredient.getId())});
    // db.close();
    // return getiIngredient(ingredient.getId());
}

public Ingredient getIngredient(final long id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.query
            (TABLE_NAME, new String[]{KEY_ID, COL_NAME, COL_AMOUNT},
            KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},
            null, null, null);

    Ingredient ingredient = null;

    if(c != null && c.getCount() > 0) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        ingredient = new Ingredient(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_NAME)));
        ingredient.setId(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
        ingredient.setAmount(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_AMOUNT)));
    }
    db.close();
    return ingredient;
}
```

**This Is My Model Class**

```
public class Ingredient implements Serializable {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String amount;

    public Zutaten() {
        this(null, null);
    }

    public Zutaten(String name) {
        this(name, null);
    }

    public Zutaten(String name, String amount) {
        this.name = name;
        this.amount= amount;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(String amount) {
        this.amount= amount;
    }
}
```

**EDIT: This is my activity where i want to show the DB Content:**

```
public class StorageDB extends AppCompatActivity {
    myDB dbIngredients;

    ListView lvDB;
    TextView name, amount;

    ArrayList<Ingredients> dataSource;
    DbStorageAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ingredient_storage);

        lvDB= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvDB);
        dataSource = dbIngredients.getInstance(this).getAllIngredient();

        this.adapter = new DbStorageAdapter (dataSource, this);
        lvDB.setAdapter(adapter);

        name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        amount= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvAmount);

        showDBcontent();
    }

     private void showDBcontent(){
        myDB db = new myDB (this);
        ArrayList<Ingredients> iList = db.getAllIngredient();
        adapter = new DbStorageAdapter (zList, this);
        lvDB.setAdapter(adapter);
     }
}
```

So if i use update, the listview in my storage activity is empty, and if i use insert all the rows from the database will be shown.

With the first click i add 8 rows to the database. If i use db.insert and click on the button i have 16 rows in my database, and all 16 rows will be shown in the storage activity.

**SECOND EDIT:**

In fact I just want that my code checks after button click if the table exists. If it exists i want that it will update my table rows. If the table does not exist I want that it insert my content which is send by button click.

I tried this, but it does not work:

```
public Ingredient increaseIngredient (final Ingredient ingredient ){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery
            ("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL_NAME + " = ?",
                    null);
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(COL_NAME, ingredient .getName());
    values.put(COL_AMOUNT, ingredient .getAmount());

   if(c !=null && c.getCount() > 0){
        db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(zutaten.getId())});
        db.close();
        return getZutat(zutaten.getId());
    } else {
        long newID = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
        return getZutat(newID);
    }
```

Comment: `db.insert` will definitely insert a new row into your table. Can you check what does `db.update` returns? It basically returns the number of rows updated. It might be returning 0 in your case.

Comment: @RickSanchez yes it returns 0, what do i have to change that it will work?

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(ingredient.getId())});
```

would update the row with `id` = `ingredient.getId()` if this id exists in the table.
When you call:

```
myDB.getInstance(MainActivity.this).increaseIngredient(ingredient);
```

the `ingredient` object does not contain the `id` that you want to update.
If you do something like this:

```
ingredient.setId(10);
```

prior to calling `increaseIngredient()` then if there exists a row with id = 10, then this row will be updated.
**Edit from comments**:
I mean something like this:

```
public Ingredient increaseIngredient (Ingredient ingredient) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COL_NAME, ingredient.getName());
    values.put(COL_AMOUNT, ingredient.getAmount());

    if (ingredient.getId() == null) {
        long newID = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
        return ???;
    } else {
        db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(ingredient.getId())});
        db.close();
        return ???;
    }
}
```

The question marks mean I don't know what you need to return.

Comment: so i added `ingredients.setId(i)` to my button click event. but still, with `db.insert` it adds a new row to my table, and with `db.uprade` nothing is shown .. what am i missing?

Comment: The id .must already exist in the table in order to be updated. When you do `ingredients.setId(i)` probably inside a loop, are you sure that there exists a row in your table that has id = i?

Comment: the id was there, but now i changed the version to test again, so when i click on the button it doesnot insert it. how can i rewrite my code, that it checks if the row exist and use upragde and otherwise it will use insert?

Comment: When you have an id then you know that the row exists right? When you want to insert a new row, you don't know the id of the row until after it is inserted. This is why you do this: `long newID = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);` to get the new id. So I don't understand what you are trying to do here. Edit your question and explain.

Comment: okay i see .. with the first click on the button i want to create the table with all my ingredients .. all clicks which will follow should just update the table rows. so i do not know how to write the if statement to select insert for the first time and upgrade for all following clicks

Comment: One way to distinguish what you will do inside `increaseIngredient()` is by checking `ingredient.getid()` (I believe you have such a method). When you pass `ingredient` with `null` or `0` as id then you will insert, but if you pass it with a number > 0 then you must update.

Comment: googled some other solutions, but unfortunately nothing of this helps me. i just do not know how to write the if statement. In SECOND EDIT you can see what i have tried.

Comment: okay thanks, but unfortunately i get `Operator == cannot be applied to long, null` tried to change my ID in my Model Class to String, but it still does not work

Comment: If it was `Long` instead of `long` it would work, but it also can work if you pass `0` and check `if (ingredient.getId() == 0)`.  I can't tell why it *does not work*. You must debug to find where the problem is.

Comment: okay .. thanks anyway. i hope to find a solution soon. unfortunately if i use `if(ingredient.getId() == 0` it will only use `insert`one time and not for all new ingredientes

Comment: `if(ingredient.getId() == 0` will be checked every time you call `increaseIngredient()`

Comment: had to remove my `ingredient.getId(i)` in my button click method, but still if i want to overwrite my table it still uses the `db.insert` .. i tested with `if(ingredients.getId == 0)` .. when i added ingredients the first time it worked great, but if i want to overwrite it it still adds new rows instead of updating the rows

Comment: In your button click method you must **set** the id. If you set it to 0 then the row will be inserted, if you set it to say 10 then the row with id = 10 will be updated.